# D3 Datamaps : Pass additional values related to data on click of country

Tags: javascript, d3.js, datamaps

I am using [mark's maps](http://github.com/markmarkoh/datamaps) for drawing graphs. I want to alert additional values related to country and not only country name. But only geography object is available inside `onClick` function. How do I access other data like

> 'numberOfThings'

inside `onClick` function?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To setup a click handler, you'll need to use the `done` callback of Datamaps. Inside the click handler, you can use the `id` from the geography object to reference the `map.options.data` object to look up the relevant data.

A working example, where only the USA has some extra data, would be the following:

```
map = new Datamap({
    scope: 'world',
    element: document.getElementById('container1'),
    projection: 'mercator',
    height: 500,
    fills: {
      defaultFill: '#f0af0a',
      lt50: 'rgba(0,244,244,0.9)',
      gt50: 'red'
    },

    data: {
      USA: {fillKey: 'lt50', numberOfThings: 120132 },
      RUS: {fillKey: 'lt50' },
      CAN: {fillKey: 'lt50' },
      BRA: {fillKey: 'gt50' },
      ARG: {fillKey: 'gt50'},
      COL: {fillKey: 'gt50' },
      AUS: {fillKey: 'gt50' },
      ZAF: {fillKey: 'gt50' },
      MAD: {fillKey: 'gt50' }       
    },

    done: function(map) {

      map.svg.selectAll('.datamaps-subunit').on('click', function(geo) {
        var localData = map.options.data[geo.id]
        if ( localData && localData.numberOfThings ) {
          alert(localData.numberOfThings)
        }
      })
    }
  })
```

Link to demo: http://jsbin.com/nigifuyeqe/1/edit?html,output

Comment: This helped me alot. Thank you.

Comment: @markmarkoh ,boss this is a good demonstration, but my question is  how can i achieve to show different country based map on a different div when clicking on world map ..
when i doing stuff like that the projection is always going wrong..

thanks in advance..